# Facebook SDK for Unity - Share link from app won't show on my friends' news feed

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm using latest Facebook SDK (7.3) for Unity in my mobile app for Android/iOS. I created an app in Facebook developers, and made it live for public. I have not yet chose to "Submit Items for Approval" because I don't know what it does and not sure it relates to my scenario.

From Unity, I use FB.ShareLink(...) to share my links and description. Everything works fine, I choose to share to public in the dialog and I see my share on my wall, BUT no one of my friends sees my share on their wall. Not even my wife who sees every other post I make.
My friends can only see this post when they specifically enter my profile page.

What am I doing wrong? Is it related to the fact I haven't sumitted my app for approval?

Please don't tell me it's by design because that would make this feature useless...

Thanks!
Noam

Comment: First off, I'd just like to make sure you misspoke when you said your link doesn't show up on your friends' walls. A person's "wall" is their profile page and there is no way to mass post to all your friends' pages. A person's News Feed is where they see posts from all their friends. This is where your share link *should* be showing up.

Have your wife go to your profile and under the "Following" dropdown, select "See First." This will make it so any of your posts will be temporarily pinned to the top of her Feed. Once you share, check that the privacy setting is in fact set to Public.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed meant the news feed- will change the subject. And it didn't help, she still can't see my post. A good friend of mine also shared from his mobile device and I didn't see it as well.

Comment: Anyone else can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry , it wasn't the answer.
        After 6 hours of intense searching, i did it ->**

```
public void PublishFacebook(){
System.Uri contentURL = new System.Uri("https://www.facebook.com/");
System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("http://example/image.jpg");

FB.ShareLink(
  contentURL,

  "I'm playing. \nAvaible on PlayStore.",
  "I made 50points",
  uri,
  null);
}
```

Comment: and i'm using this > 
    public void FBlogin() {
        List<string> permissions = new List<string>();
        permissions.Add("public_profile");
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(permissions, AuthCallBack);
    }

Comment: need to set permission to public before  ( "public_profile"). I hope it helps you :)